# Show any data in Scala Play 2 without refresh page

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is there any way to do this? As usually I use flash-scope for show any message look like this:

```
Redirect(Ok(views.html.myform(data))).flashing("success"->"any message")
```

But it always refresh page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want a dynamic webpage that can change how it looks without needing to reload? Sounds like you want to use Javascript!

Rather than redirecting the browser and setting the result on Play's Flashing cookie, make the call from Javascript and return a json object like `{"success": "any message"}`. Then, in the Javascript, handle the response by updating something on the page to show a success message.